# End User Ad-Hoc Reporting Tool: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, reporting, adhoc

Our centralized IT department has suggested two primary ad hoc query tools for our general user base of approximately 200 staff members:

1. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (SSMS)
2. Microsoft Access 2003

**Environment**

- The backend database is a read-only Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database.
- The schema is 400+ tables; allowing access to the raw data for our general staff would be a disaster.
- We will be building an "abstraction layer" over the raw data for our general staff to run ad hoc queries against.
- The abstraction layer will most likely contain a number of views.
- A number of users have basic knowledge in Microsoft Access; none have used SSMS.

Which of the above tools (or alternative) would be best for a decidedly **non-techie** user base of approximately 200 people? What are the pros and cons of each?

Also, the IT department has suggested teaching people T-SQL so they may use SSMS. Is this reasonable?

Comment: What will they be doing with it? That will likely determine the direction you'll need to go in.

Comment: "Also, the IT department has suggested teaching people T-SQL so they may use SSMS. Is this reasonable?"   I doubt even power users are going to want to know that level of detail.   My power users are comfortable creating and running their own queries in Access using the drag and drop features.  I very much doubt they ever dropped to SQL design view.  But then they didn't have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "abstraction layer" is the right approach to take with Access.   Create an MDB with the basic views required linked into it and distribute to the users.  Allow them to create new queries and reports in their own MDB as required.

Now how you are going to stop them from running a Cartesian join on tables with a million records or more I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks Tony. :) Excellent point to keep in consideration. Our largest table is maybe 100K records at this point, but we are still in the middle of implementation, so that number could quite likely eventually get up to a million or more.

Comment: +1 Access MDB is the way to go if you want to give users the ability to make their own queries

Answer (score 6):

How about this one? **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be called i-net Crystal-Clear) has a powerful ad-hoc reporting component that is made to be an easy-to-use thing for non-technical users. Your users won't have to know anything about reporting at all. They simply select the kind of report, the data et voila there is a report suiting the needs.

The data abstraction can be done easily by creating so called data-views which can be designed by e.g. your administration. There are various ways to access the ad hoc reporting GUI. We have a web GUI, a Java Applet or a standalone Java program.

- The end users will not need any training since the GUI is highly intuitive.
- The views can easily be build by drag and drop in addition to setting datatypes, formats and so on.
- All reports (depending on security settings) can be accessed via DAV our a report repository gui.
- The server supports different security settings on a per user or per group basis.
- The standalone [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) is free and fully functional.

Disclosure: Yep. I work for the company who built this.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft have a free tool for business and end users which called "Report Builder". It supports the full capabilities of SQL Server Reporting Services. The good thing it is provides a Microsoft Office look-like user interface.

You can download latest version "Report Builder 3.0" from here
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=6116

And for more information about MS Report Builder check this link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to teach "non-techie" people T-SQL to query a schema with 400+ tables probably isn't going to do well, unless they are limited to querying the views only, and the views hide all the ugly complexities of various joins, grouping etc.

Our company was in a similar situation where Access was used early on, and then we switched everyone over to use T-SQL and SSMS. IMO, this is the approach you'd want to take.

Again though, the success of this will depend on the quality of your views, or better yet, reports you provide your end-users.

Randy

Comment: Thanks Randy. Is there a way in SSMS to limit visibility to just views? I know in Microsoft Access I can use database links to backend database objects (for example, views) to hide the 400+ tables from end-users. How about in SSMS?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. But I suspect you can hide the tables via permissions, but I'm not that familiar with SQL Server security.

Comment: As part of your SQL Server security users would not be able to see tables where they are denied all permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I would look more into something like [Stonefieldquery.com](http://www.stonefieldquery.com) that is designed for non developers to build reports. Not that the report writer or query builder in Access is bad, but may be too much. I think they also provide a way to centralize reports and queries where they can be shared. Multiple people are not going to be able to open a single access file and create a report (I think query building is OK.).

Most will use the drag and drop capability, but about 5-10%will come thing a need for SQL and then you can take advantage of the "teachable moment" and get them some training.

Comment: Thanks GuinnessFan. :) Very insightful on the ratios of general users to power users. My intuition tells me this seems about right. For the 80%+ of general users, we need something we can roll out fairly easily. I am mostly concerned about what pitfalls we will run into using SSMS with a general audience. I use it all the time in my IT role.

Comment: I worked at a firm where accountants used SSMS and Excel for everything. They took courses in both. They did not like being switched to report writing software because a) they prefered text sql and the text version in this app was bad (similar to access). b) they did not know how to take advantage of the sharing and reusability of this app. In their mind, everything was unique, one-off, ad hoc etc. - very territorial in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Cons for Access certainly would be cost; SSMS should be free assuming you're properly licensed for the SQL server.

Depending on the actual needs, some users might actually be better off with Crystal Reports (never thought I'd say that), or Reporting Services.

Comment: Thanks SqlACID. :) SSRS and Report Builder were my first choices but IT and business management have chosen this strategy instead. All 200 employees have an installed user base of Microsoft Access 2003, so that cost should hopefully not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a series of sql server analysis cubes and have the users conenct to those using excel so that they can use excel's pivot tables.

Comment: Thanks Thirster42! :) I had not considered that option. What downsides would there be to this approach?

Comment: mainly maintenance.  you'd have to create enough cubes to cover what they want (or jsut throw all 400 in one cube).  and also security.

Comment: also, you can set up data sets in reporting services and let users create their own reports inside report manager.

Answer (score 0):

Being a newbie at ad hoc reporting and doing the work myself, I used Izenda.com ad hoc reporting.  It was very straight forward, and I could do it myself versus outsourcing.

Comment: Its an old post, but since it will be looked up as reference it makes sense to add your experience here even after this time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check SQLS*Plus - http://www.sqlsplus.com

I found SQLS*Plus to be a very effective command line SQL server reporting tool - this is a free tool (for personal use) and allows me to generate reports with the titles, headers, in HTML and CSV formats, format columns in custom masks, set report length, pagesize, etc. As I understand it is very similar to very well known Oracle SQL*Plus reporting tool